# why the performance of my scatter code better than Vc SIMD?

Tags: c++, simd

I'm a rookie to SIMD program

```
unsigned int Hash(unsigned int f);
uint_v Hash(uint_v vec);

int main()
{
        std::random_device rd;
        unsigned* mem1=new unsigned [_size]();
        for(int i=0;i<_size;++i)
                mem1[i]=rd();

        time_t t1=clock();
        uint_v mem;
        for(int i=0;i<_size;i+=uint_v::size())
        {
                mem.load(mem1+i,Vc::Unaligned);
                uint_v temp=Hash(mem);
        }
        t1=clock()-t1;
        std::cout<<"simd time:"<<(1.0*t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"\n";

        time_t t2=clock();
        for(int i=0;i<_size;++i)
                unsigned int temp=Hash(mem1[i]);
        t2=clock()-t2;
        std::cout<<"normal time:"<<(1.0*t2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"\n";

        return 0;
}
unsigned int Hash(unsigned int f)
{
        return (f>>7)^(f>>13)^(f>>21)^f;
}
uint_v Hash(uint_v vec)
{
        uint_v mem=vec.apply([](unsigned f) ->unsigned{return (f>>7)^(f>>13)^(f>>21)^f;});
        return mem;
}
```

my code as above,the time result is:
**simd time:0.127762
normal time:0.034841**
result is similar with comparing the date in mem1 and mem2(Vc uint_v vector)

Comment: What's `uint_v`?  I don't see a definition for that anywhere in what you posted.  Your vectorized Hash function isn't a drop-in replacement if the signature is different.  Also, what compile options did you use?  (specifically, was optimization enabled?  Without optimization, extra layers of code (like `.apply`) won't actually optimize away.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for your response,my compile options g++ -o3 xxxxx,  and the **uint_v** is a Vector type define in SIMD lib Vc,containing 128/256 bits data.

Comment: You should link to this Vc library you're talking about.  I had no idea what it was, or that you were even talking about a library.  I assumed it was some kind of (Microsoft) Visual C thing.

Comment: Also important: what hardware are you testing on?  Intel Nehalem?  Haswell?  ARM something?  If x86-64, you're just using the baseline SSE2, not `-msse4` or `-mavx`?  BTW, `gcc -o3` writes the output to a file called `3`.  I assume you meant `gcc -O3`.

Comment: @PeterCordes my CPU is Haswell i5-4590,I can not specify the -mavx2 compile option because of the lib Vc will cause lots of errors with it. the -o3 is my fault,thank you again

Comment: @PeterCordes Vc is a opensource library I found in github which wrap the SIMD intrinsics

Comment: You can [edit] that info into your question, where other people will see it right away when they look at your question, instead of seeing it's a bad question and maybe moving on without reading comments.  Also, you should include the actual URL for the library so people can go look at it if they want.

Comment: If the library you're using doesn't compile with `-mavx2`, you should maybe look at another library, like Agner Fog's GPLed [Vector Class Library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) is a good thin wrapper with classes like `Vec4i` or `Vec16c` around the basic `__m128i` / `__m256i` type.  (And similar wrappers for single / double precision float vectors).

Comment: @PeterCordes the VCL is cool,it solved my problems,thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not measuring what you intended to measure. The compiler will do dead code elimination for everything that you calculate but never use (well, everything where the compiler is 100% that it's never used).
The compiler should have done DCE on both loops but apparently failed to do it for the Vc case.

Ideas:

- store the result to a global variable
- use inline asm to fake a use of the result